# Trying to pass a HTML element to a react component as a text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am trying to pass a text that has basically a new line to separate a larger sentence. I am trying to parse it as a react element by including it within the fragments. Still I get the `[object][Object]` instead of adding this newline.

Its basically a semantic-ui-react loader that I am passing the text to.

Somewhere in the code I am setting the state and then invoking the component

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-y8e38?file=/example.js

```
//Setting the state
this.setState({ text: `You will be redirected , and you may need to login.${<><br/></>} .Please read the conditions`});

 //Calling the component
 <MyComp
          message={text}

 />

 //Called Component
  import { Loader } from "semantic-ui-react";
  const MyComp: React.FunctionComponent<IProps> = props => {
    return (
       <>
        <Loader>{props.message}</Loader>
       </>   
    );
};
```

Can some one help me here?

Comment: this looks like a bug in your code: `<p>{props.message}</Loader>`  maybe this is the problem.  should be: `<p>{props.message}</p>`

Comment: So, what does loader look like??  as this is where your problem is...

Comment: this is the loader https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/loader/#types-text

Comment: I am passing the text to it, since the text is a bit lengthy, I tried to add a line break. It showed "You will be redirected , and you may need to login [object Object] .Please read the conditions"

Comment: Hi @li97, I'm having trouble understanding what that link is showing me...  I think rather than trying to embed a `<br/>` into your text, pass the text as an array of lines, then in your Loader component (or where ever the text is to be rendered) you can map these to lines of html of your choosing

Comment: check the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-y8e38?file=/example.js

Comment: ok i can see what you are trying to do now - I'll post an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The HTML you pass to react component as string cannot be rendered directly unless you use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
//Setting the state
this.setState({ text: `You will be redirected , and you may need to login.<br/>.Please read the conditions`});

 //Calling the component
 <MyComp
          message={text}
 />

 //Called Component
  const MyComp: React.FunctionComponent<IProps> = props => {
    return (
       <>
        <Loader><p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.message}}/></Loader>
       </>   
    );
};
```

However the use of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is discouraged and the best way to handle such scenarios is to pass on the html as children and enable it conditionally

```
//Setting the state
this.setState({ showText: true});

 //Calling the component
 <MyComp>
      {this.state.showText? <span>You will be redirected , and you may need to login. <br/> .Please read the conditions</span>: null}
 </MyComp>

 //Called Component
  import { Loader } from "semantic-ui-react";
  const MyComp: React.FunctionComponent<IProps> = props => {
    return (
       <>
        <Loader>{props.children}</Loader>
       </>   
    );
};
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-kh44i?file=/example.js)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add , its a semantic-ui-react Loader component to which I need to send this text

Comment: This answer make no sense to me.  The Loader element is invalid HTML, and you can set text in an element.

Comment: @developer It made sense before the edit because OP had <p> element there

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri You have edited it now, to be at least valid HTML.

Comment: @developer Look at the proper edit now. Thinks always need not be exactly correct. Sometimes the logic is more important

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, did not work , shows blank

Comment: Which approach did you try?

Comment: I'm sure this approach will also work..  @li97 what are we missing?

Comment: Loader needs to have an active props or else it will not be shown. Working demo https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-kh44i?file=/example.js

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri your approach may not be working for him because you renamed his component to `Spinner` in first example - i prefer your second anyway

Comment: @developer the OP updated his question multiple times. I didn't rename anything. I just copied the first snippet that was shown. Also I added a working demo based on the above approach

Comment: I agree there was a lot of churn with his question, but it doesn't change the fact that your answer is syntactically wrong, to be useful to other visitors of this question.  I like your second answer :)

Comment: Added demo for both approaches

Answer (score 0):

Working from your code, you are passing in a prop called: message which contains the text you want to display in the loader.

in your code this would be:

```
//Setting the state
this.setState(
  { 
     texts: [
        "You will be redirected, and you may need to login.", 
        "Please read the conditions"
     ] 
  });
```

Note: I've changed this to text(s)  as it is now an array..

As before create an instance of you component:

```
<MyComp messages={texts} />
```

passing texts in via the prop messages (renamed messages as it is now an array)

Then in your loader you can split the lines like this:

```
<Loader>{messages.map( m => <span>{m}</span><br/>)}</Loader>
```

this is adding the messages each separated by a `<br/>`

I'm sure you can come up with some better variable names :)

Comment: i dont want to pass it as an array, may be as a single line of text. this is kind of a general loader component, where it loads the spinner with a single message

Comment: then you can either simply add a wrapper (HOC) to specialise it when required, or you have a message, and a messages prop, so user can pass either an array or a single.  Or even test if messages is an array in your component and do the right thing

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to add some conditionText which will be in next line

```
//Setting the state
this.setState({ 
  redirectText: "You will be redirected , and you may need to login.", 
  conditionText: "Please read the conditions"
});

 //Calling the component
 <MyComp
    redirectText={this.state.redirectText}
    conditionText={this.state.conditionText}
 />

 //Called Component
  import { Loader } from "semantic-ui-react";
  const MyComp: React.FunctionComponent<IProps> = props => {
    return (
       <>
        <Loader>
          <div>{props.redirectText}</div>
          <div>{props.conditionText}</div>
        </Loader>
       </>   
    );
};
```